# Rails - conditional query with nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Any ideas what's wrong with this?

```
    @contacts = current_user.contacts.where("fname = ? OR lname = ?", nil, nil)
```

I want all contacts where either the fname or lname is empty.

Here is what it shows in the logs, not sure why it's not getting the records.

```
 Contact Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE ("contacts".user_id = 2) AND (fname = NULL OR lname = NULL)
```

Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want empty (meaning a blank string, but not actually null), then use an empty string:

```
@contacts = current_user.contacts.where("fname = ? OR lname = ?", "", "")
```

Otherwise, if you truly want the null values, you need to use the `is null` wording:

```
@contacts = current_user.contacts.where("fname is null OR lname is null")
```

You can also use `:lname => nil` instead, but that format can't be used for OR queries. Note the different between `"lname = ?", nil`  and `:lname => nil`:

```
@contacts = Contact.where("lname = ?", nil).to_sql
# => SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE (lname = NULL)

@contacts = Contact.where(:lname => nil).to_sql
# => SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."lname" IS NULL
```